# Unparseable date at offset 12

Tags: android

```
SimpleDateFormat df1 =new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
String CurrentDate = df1.format(c.getTime());

try {
    Date date = df1.parse(CurrentDate);
     System.out.println( date );
} catch (ParseException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Note: I want to parse String date into Date Datatype but i got Unparseable date exception on 4th line. i already tried many other options but didnt get any output. Many Experts tell me to do like this. but i got error. help me to get out of this problem.

Comment: Why format & parse? Use `Date date = c.getTime()`.

Comment: i need date in MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss format.

Comment: Take a look at your code. You've formatted date & time in `CurrectDate` string variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need date in MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss format try below code

```
SimpleDateFormat df1 =new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
String CurrentDate = df1.format(new Date().getTime());
System.out.println( CurrentDate );
```

Comment: i want output in date datatype. not in String.